# resteasy @Consume json fails with java.util.Map

Tags: java, resteasy

I have the following json structure:

```
{
    "foo" : {
        "foo1" : {
            "txt" : "val",
            "txt1" : "val1",
            "txt2" : "val2",
        },
        "foo2" : {
            "txt" : "val",
            "txt1" : "val1",
            "txt2" : "val2",
        }
    },
    "bar" : {
        "bar1": {
            "txt" : "val",
            "txt1" : "val1",
            "txt2" : "val2",
        },
        "bar2": {
            "txt" : "val",
            "txt1" : "val1",
            "txt2" : "val2",
        }
    }
}
```

While i have the following pojo:

```
class Pojo {
  String txt;
  String txt1;
  String txt2;
}
```

And my resteasy method looks like:

```
@POST
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Path("/foo")
public void bar(@QueryParam("jsonObj") Map<String,Map<String,Pojo>> jsonObj);
```

However while starting the server i get the following error:

> **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a constructor that takes a
>   String param or a valueOf() or fromString() method for
>   javax.ws.rs.QueryParam("jsonObj") on public abstract void
>   com.foo.FooBar.bar(java.util.Map) for basetype: java.util.Map**   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.StringParameterInjector.initialize(StringParameterInjector.java:217)
>   ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.jar:na]  at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.StringParameterInjector.(StringParameterInjector.java:61)
>   ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.jar:na]  at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.QueryParamInjector.(QueryParamInjector.java:28)
>   ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.jar:na]  at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.InjectorFactoryImpl.createParameterExtractor(InjectorFactoryImpl.java:85)
>   ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.jar:na]  at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.(MethodInjectorImpl.java:42)
>   ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.jar:na]  at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.InjectorFactoryImpl.createMethodInjector(InjectorFactoryImpl.java:76)
>   ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.jar:na]  at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:100)
>   ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.jar:na]  at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.processMethod(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:280)
>   ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.jar:na]  at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.register(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:251)
>   ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.jar:na]  at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:221)
>   ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.jar:na]  at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:193)
>   ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.jar:na]  at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:179)
>   ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.jar:na]  at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringBeanProcessor.onApplicationEvent(SpringBeanProcessor.java:486)
>   ~[resteasy-spring-3.0.9.Final.jar:na]     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:96)
>   ~[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
>   ~[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:948)
>   ~[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>   ~[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
>   ~[spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>   ~[spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
>   [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SpringContextLoaderListener.java:48)
>   [resteasy-spring-3.0.9.Final.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.47]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.47]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.47]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.47]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.47]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0-45]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [na:1.7.0-45]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [na:1.7.0-45]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0-45]

I went through the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.2.1.GA/userguide/html/StringConverter.html) and for Complex Objects it says to use StringConvertor, but shouldn't it be supported for a simple types like List, Map etc...

Comment: As the error message (and the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2153)) states, you can't automatically inject parameters into a map as it is an interface and therefore has no constructor with only a single parameter and no `valueOf()` or `fromString()` methods. You can however try to define a custom [`javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverter` implementation](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/blob/master/jaxrs/paramconverter/src/main/java/org/javaee7/jaxrs/paramconverter/MyConverterProvider.java) which creates a Map for you.

Comment: Furthermore, do you really provide this JSON structure as query-parameter?

Comment: So in my custom convertor in the fromString, i would have to parse the json and convert into a Map assign back to the Map? If that's the case then i'm better off just accepting the param as a string and converting it there itself

Comment: "Furthermore, do you really provide this JSON structure as query-parameter?" Good point. Since it's a POST i think i'm better off using the @FormParam

Comment: None of the parameter annotations is appropriate in this case as you obviously send the JSON as body in a POST request. Do you have control over the JSON format? If so, change it to contain lists of foo's (or bar's) which furthermore contain lists of foo1's (or bar1's) which actually contain your pojo and update your pojo to fit the modified design. If not, simply use an InputStream or String method parameter (withoug any annotations) and create the object on your own (or use a MessageBodyReader to convert the input-stream to your pojos).

Comment: Just curious, why do you think none of the param annotations would work? Also whats the benefit in changing the json schema?

Comment: Actually, using [form submit may allow you to pass JSON](https://darobin.github.io/formic/specs/json/) (note: draft is unofficial) to a `@FormParam` annotated parameter, though it has the [same restrictions](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html) as the other parameters. And why trying to inject JSON data you received into a `@*Param` annotated object when you can simply inject it as [String, InputStream or any other of the supported types](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking the JSON in Map> jsonObj format , you can use InputStream and then you can process the input stream to get the objects out of it.